# Identify contry code from phonenumber

Tags: .net, backbone.js

I have a "small" problem
I have some exitsting phonenumber that contain the country code and phonenumber.

I need to split these into country code and phonenumber.
Anyone know a way to do this.

I have the complete list of country codes so I could just start from the beginning and test if there is a match. But this dosen't strike me as the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing solution (library\module) for this issue. 
I think that the best solution for it is:

Split the list of country codes into 4 lists: a list of 1-digit country codes, a list of 2-digit country codes, 3-digit country codes and 4-digit country codes.

Now :

> Run recursively the next algorithm on N=4...1 (starting from 4):
>
> - check if the number's first N digits match any of the codes from the list of N digits
>
>   - if none match - try the next iteration on N-1.
>   - if you reached N=0 - no codes match.
>   - if a code was found - check the length of the rest of the number and validate 
>       that its length is legal
>   - if not - carry on iterating on the algorithm.

Comment: This might be dooable...
thanks for the quick response